# Trigger updates with different values on batch and single record entry. How do I fix this?

Tags: apex, trigger, map

```
public static list<Opportunity>LeadAndBackupUsers(list<Opportunity> opps){
    set<id> accountIds = new set<id>();
    for(Opportunity o : opps){
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
    }
    Account[] acounts = [select id,Lead_Advisor__c,Advisory_Associate__c from Account where id IN:accountIds];
    for(Opportunity opp: opps){
        if(acounts.size()>0){
            for(Account acount: acounts){
                if(acount.Lead_Advisor__c <> null)
                    opp.Client_Lead_Advisor__c = acount.Lead_Advisor__c;
                if(acount.Advisory_Associate__c <> null)
                    opp.Advisory_Associate__c = acount.Advisory_Associate__c;
            }
        }

    }


return opps;    
}
```

The code works perfectly well when I am updating one record but when I am loading lots of record via dataloader, something is a miss (wrong assignments). Is my code not optimized correctly? What is the best way of fixing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a loop inside a loop, so the inner logic is being applied each time from each opportunity. The net result is that the last account in the list will end up overwriting each time. Instead, you meant to do this:

```
public static opportunity[] leadAndBackupUsers(Opportunity[] opps) {
    map<id, account> accounts = new map<id, account>();
    for(Opportunity record:opps) {
        accounts.put(record.accountid,null);
    }
    accounts.remove(null);
    accounts.putAll([select id,lead_advisor__c,advisory_associate__c from account where id in :accounts.keyset()]);
    for(opportunity record:opps) {
        if(accounts.containskey(record.accountid)) {
            if(accounts.get(record.accountid).lead_advisor__c != null) {
                record.client_lead_advisor__c = accounts.get(record.accountid).lead_advisor__c;
            }
            if(accounts.get(record.accountid).advisory_associate__c != null) {
                record.advisory_associate__c = accounts.get(record.accountid).advisory_associate__c;
            }
        }
    }
    return opps;
}
```

It should also be noted that Apex Code is a "reference-based" language. This means that returning `opps` is unnecessary, as these two examples have the same effect:

```
leadAndBackupUsers(opps);
opps = leadAndBackupUsers(opps);
```

This works because `opps` is passed *by memory reference*, not by *copy*; copy would imply that the function's `opps` parameter is a duplicate of the original list, i.e. it occupies a different area of memory.

Comment: Thanks.. it works. Was trying to see if it could be done without maps but I guess there is no other way around it.

Comment: @Kenn Maps are your friend! Learn them ... love them

Comment: That's the purpose of a map. If you have to use a for loop inside a for loop, you're probably doing something wrong. You *could* do it without a map, but a set of 200 opportunities with 200 accounts in a trigger would result in 40,000 lines of script execution just to execute the loop.